# What's happening in the bind call? (python + socket + strace)

Tags: python, linux, sockets, kernel, internals

For kicks I wrote the following echo server in python.
http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/echoserver.html  (I think I copied the code from here.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

host = ''
port = 50000
backlog = 5
size = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
```

Then I ran strace -o /tmp/somefile -v ipython
And started inserting pieces of code line by line.

Most of the output makes sense but I can't figure the following.

```
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=3084, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendto(4, "\24\0\0\0\26\0\1\3\300EPO\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
recvmsg(4, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"0\0\0\0\24\0\2\0\300EPO\f\f\0\0\2\10\200\376\1\0\0\0\10\0\1\0\177\0\0\1"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 108
recvmsg(4, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"@\0\0\0\24\0\2\0\300EPO\f\f\0\0\n\200\200\376\1\0\0\0\24\0\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 128
recvmsg(4, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\24\0\0\0\3\0\2\0\300EPO\f\f\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\24\0\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 20
close(4)
```

The strace output above is followed by the following output.  The output above only happens in python2.6.

```
listen(3, 5)                            = 0
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(45636), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 4
recvfrom(4, "Hey", 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 3
sendto(4, "Heyback", 7, 0, NULL, 0)     = 7
close(4)                                = 0
accept(3, 0x7fffdac55fe0, [16])         = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
```

This is more of an academic exercise, the server runs just fine but I'd liked to know what's going on with file descriptor 4?  Why does it only occur in python2.6?

Answer (score 3):

I'd expect that line to be preceded by something like

```
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 4
```

`man 7 netlink` tells us the format of what's sent, and so we can decode the sent message as the concatenation of

```
struct nlmsghdr _ = {
    .nlmsglen = 20,
    .nlmsg_type = RTM_GETADDR,
    .nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ROOT | NLM_F_MATCH;
    .nlmsg_seq = 1330660800,
    .nlmsg_pid = 0,
};
```

and some four bytes of zero.

What is RTM_GETADDR?  `man 7 rtnetlink` says it's a request for IP address information about each interface.  We could decode the `struct ifaddrmsg` of the body of the responses, but the netlink headers on the front of each makes strace cut the data output short.

In any case, I'd be happy to stop here and assume it's simply retrieving information needed to fill out `struct sockaddr_in` in order to call `bind`.  After all, you did pass in an empty node name, so it has nothing to work off of.  Confirming this, if you change `''` to `'0.0.0.0'` (for "bind to any address on any interface"), you no longer see this little exchange.